# How to generate API key in Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am new in using swagger and apis. I can't figure out how to generate an api key using Swagger. Can someone guide me in right direction? Thanks

Comment: What is the context here? Are you the API developer? Are you trying to write an OpenAPI (Swagger) definition for an API that requires an API key? Or are you the API consumer? In the latter case, the API key should be provided to you by the API developer.

Comment: I am not an api developer. The api is already previously made by some people. Now the task is to secure the api. I am working on it and require an api key. I have searched the internet but was unable to find the proper documentation regarding swagger and how to generate a key related to swagger api.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a way to generate an API key in swagger Open API 3.0 . I am
> logged in to my account under my company in Swagger and when  I select my
> profile icon on the navigation bar at the upper right , it will provide a drop-down bar  like
> the following image: [enter image description here]

[image]

> If, however, you need to generate an API Key  to connect Swagger Hub
> to a specific API platform , you could look at this example concerning
> how to do this using IBM Cloud:

[https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/ibm-api-connect.html#:~:text=SwaggerHub%20needs%20an%20API%20key%20to%20connect%20to,description%20for%20this%20API%20key%20and%20click%20Create](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/ibm-api-connect.html#:%7E:text=SwaggerHub%20needs%20an%20API%20key%20to%20connect%20to,description%20for%20this%20API%20key%20and%20click%20Create).

I think you are referring to the my first answer.
Hope that helps.